# Convergence of the Series - $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{\prod_{k=1}^{n}{(3k-1)}}{\prod_{k=1}^{n}(4k-3)}$

Tags: sequences-and-series

Prove that the following series is convergent.

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{\prod_{k=1}^{n}{(3k-1)}}{\prod_{k=1}^{n}(4k-3)}$$

I don't know for where to begin.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Hint:** The Ratio Test is perfect for this. If $a_n$ is the $n$-th term, then 
$$\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}=\frac{3n+2}{4n+1}.$$

**Detail:** Note that 
$$a_{n+1}=\frac{\prod_1^{n+1} (3k-1)}{\prod_1^{n+1} (4k-3)}.$$
But 
$$\prod_{k=1}^{n+1}(3k-1)=\left(\prod_1^n (3k-1)\right)\left(3(n+1)-1\right),$$
and 
$$\prod_{k=1}^{n+1}(4k-3)=\left(\prod_1^n (4k-3)\right)\left(4(n+1)-3\right).$$
Now when we calculate $\dfrac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}$, we see there is very nice cancellation.

Comment: I applied the ratio test but didn't find this result. My ratio test gives me:

$$\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n} = \frac{\prod{3k+2}.\prod{4k-3}}{\prod{4k+3}.\prod{3k-1}}$$

Comment: I will add the calculation. You are having trouble with the product notation.

Comment: Oh, I understood now. I just need to add one extra factor. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** You can use the ratio test.